# How do I convert an sql script into an executable .sql file?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My manager asked me to to compile a set of sql scripts, I use some of those scripts for updating new records (some are used in ssms and ssis), to create table and scripts that I use to connect the foreign keys from the dim table to the fact table.

He asked me to do this...
Can you send me the sql script used to prepare the initial environment?
Please put that into a executable .sql file.

I haven't done this before and what tools should I use? SSMS? or SSIS? or Notepad?

I am using SQL Server, the tools I have is SSMS and BIDS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export database schema into SQL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036458/export-database-schema-into-sql-file)

Comment: What is your database server?

Comment: Hi, Im using SQL Server

Comment: A ".sql" file is just plain text containing the script.

Comment: There is no such thing as an executable SQL file

Comment: So I just put the script in the New Query field in SQL server Management studio and then save it?

Comment: Yes. Just save it and email it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, write a sql statement and save. It will create a txt document with an .sql extension. 'Excuting' this file will, depending on your file associations, open SSMS and load this file. As for sending a *sql script used to prepare the initial environment*, there is no such thing. That is something that you will have to prepare; we know nothing about your environment.

I have created SQL scripts that contain many steps to help me run repetitive tasks. Run it once and all of my work is done, but I built them painstakingly by hand one-at-a-time 
[image: screenshot] 
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The is no such thing as an "executable" SQL file. There are just SQL files:

Try something like this:

```
rename myscript.txt myscript.sql
```

Or if you are using an editor:

```
Save: myscript.sql
```

Comment: You are 'technically' write that there is no such thing as an 'executable' SQL file, but executable in this case may just mean verified "valid" or "working".